# Google Sheets: Make the cell data the name of the link

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, links

Update:
I have attached a pic for example.
--------[image]
I have ID numbers in each cell and I want that number to be a link to their file.

I know how to make a *separate* hyperlink that will ref that cell to open the file but I don't know how to make the number itself the link and the title.

With the separate hyperlink I know I can tell it to pull info from cell B2 (or whatnot) and then when it's done, drag the final link down and it will auto pop to reference cell B3, B4, etc.
Not sure how to get it to refer to the ID number in the cell itself.

Help?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`=hyperlink("https://www.example.org/index.php?file=" & B2, B2)`

...where cell `B2` contains the ID.

Comment: It came back with REF error.  

So, here is what I tried:
=hyperlink("h ttps://www.miscschoolwebpage.com/home/pages/myStudent.aspx?idWebuser=" & B2, B2)

The normal webpage I'm linking to is like this:
h ttps://www.miscschoolpage.com/home/pages/myStudent.aspx?idWebuser=123456
where "123456" is actually the ID #

(I don't know how to properly format this so it won't auto link, so I put a space in the h_ttp

Comment: The URL you quote gives "This site can’t be reached". Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Answer (score 0):

I got a hold of a friend well versed in this, and he said basically, no it can't be done quite like this.

His workaround would be to continue doing it the way I am, but make a duplicate of the ID column to reference, then hide it.